# Changing Printer settings in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I am making an application that prints records and I want to set the paper height dynamically. My problem is how to change the settings of the printer programmatically in VB.Net.

Somebody told me that it could be done by going to Device and Printers, select the printer and setting it with the desired height. However, can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Can you post some of your printing code? Depending on how you've implemented the printing functionality, you should just be able to set this through the [`PrintDocument.PrinterSettings` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printersettings.aspx). No reason to change the system-wide defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [set the paper size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize.papersize.aspx) dynamically in your code within the system.drawing.printing.papersize constructor.

```
  Dim PaperHeightInt As New Integer
  Dim PaperSize As Drawing.Printing.PaperSize
  PaperSize.Height = PaperHeightInt
```